# Python import: Module's path is different, depending on where it's imported from?

Tags: python, import, module

The header might be quite hard to understand, but I'll try to explain as well as I can.

I have a folder called `SubModule` which includes total of 3 files:

```
__init__.py
Class1.py
Class2.py
```

Inside `__init__.py`, I got this:

```
import Class1
import Class2

def main():
    c1 = Class1.Class1()
    c2 = Class2.Class2()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And it all works fine with no errors, and I can use c1 and c2 properly.

---

The problem appears, when I try to move `SubModule` folder under an other module's (let's call it `MainModule`) folder.
So I would have the following:

```
MainModule\__init__.py
MainModule\SubModule\__init__.py
MainModule\SubModule\Class1.py
MainModule\SubModule\Class2.py
```

Now when I try to import `SubModule` from `MainModule\__init__.py` like so:

```
import SubModule
c1 = SubModule.ClassOne.ClassOne()
c2 = SubModule.ClassTwo.ClassTwo()
```

I would expect this to work.
However, running the `MainModule\__init__.py` raises an error from  `SubModule\__init__.py`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\...\MainModule\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import SubModule
  File "C:\...\MainModule\SubModule\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import Class1
ImportError: No module named 'Class1'
```

As you can see, the error comes from `import Class1`, and it tells me that there's `No module named 'Class1'`.
This is cause the path is now `SubModule.Class1`, instead of only `Class1`.
I can get rid of this error by changing `SubModule\__init__.py` to this:

```
import SubModule.Class1
import SubModule.Class2
```

However, I can no longer use the `SubModule` alone by running `SubModule\__init__.py`, since the path would be `import Class1` again, instead of `import SubModule.Class1`.

This is making me crazy, is there a way to generalize the importing, so it doesn't matter which module imports SubModule?

Comment: This is a strange way of doing imports.  Why don't you put SubModule in one place, add it to the system path, and always import it from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a way, not exactly 'general', but ...

```
try:
    import Submodule.Class1 as Class1
except ImportError:
    import Class1
```

Comment: I won't accept yet, if someone comes up with something better, but this'll do for now. I had similar one already, but thanks for the `as Class1` tip, didn't know that one.

Answer (score 0):

You should always import a module absolutely from the system path.  So if your package MainModule contains a subpackage SubModule, you should do `from MainModule import SubModule` (or `from . import SubModule`).  Also, inside SubModule, do `from . import Class1`.  This should let it work regardless of the path to `SubModule`.  (However, it will still cause weirdness if you import `SubModule` in two different ways -- which includes running it as the main file vs importing it.)

Comment: That sounds somewhat better, I can't test it now but I will when I get home.

Comment: I can't import `from MainModule ...`, since `No module named 'MainModule'`